# Is it possible to work with pointers in PHP?

Tags: php, pointers

So I understand that references aren't pointers: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php

Question is, is it possible to work with pointers in php?

Given the following example I would guess that's what we do when working with objects:

```
class Entity
{
  public $attr;
}

class Filter
{
  public function filter(Entity $entity)
  {
    $entity->attr = trim($entity->attr);
  }
}

$entity = new Entity;
$entity->attr = '  foo  ';
$filter = new Filter;
$filter->filter($entity);
echo $entity->attr; // > 'foo', no white space
```

Is the example above working with pointers behind the sceen or is it still swapping memory, as when working with references?

### Edit

#### A different example:

*Is the following:*

```
class Entity
{
  public $attr;
}
$entity = new Entity;
$entity->attr = 1;
$entity->attr = 2;
```

*Something like this in **C**:*

```
int* attr;
*attr = 1;
*attr = 2;
```

Comment: When you use objects, all the variables refer to the same object, and it's analogous to using pointers in a language like C or C++.

Comment: @mario in function arguments `Entity $entity` wont be a new object it will the same old one called as parameter..

Comment: defining type in functions arguments will make them strict but will not create new object. please correct me if I'm'm wrong..

Comment: @zzlalani Ah okay. So OP is asking about the implicit object references then.

Comment: updated the question with a new example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass an object as an argument to your function, the variable itself is copied but the properties it has point to those of the original object, i.e.:

```
function test(Something $bar)
{
    $bar->y = 'a'; // will update $foo->y
    $bar = 123; // will not update $foo
}

$foo = new Something;
$foo->y = 'b';
test($foo);
// $foo->y == 'a';
```

Inside the function the memory references look a bit like this:

```
$bar ---+
        +---> (object [ y => string('b') ])
$foo ---+
```

After `$bar = 123;` it looks like this:

```
$bar ---> int(123)

$foo ---> (object [ y => 'b' ])
```

Comment: Good answer, but the question is not so much about the outcome or expected behavior as you explain. The question is about how php work with the memory.

Comment: @ErikLandvall This tells exactly how it works with memory ... inside the function `$bar->y` is basically a pointer to `$foo->y`, except that there's no visible dereferencing :)

Comment: Ok, I find it hard to see in when explained in php. Could you resumble the same code in **C**. It would help a lot.

Comment: The reason I ask for this is because the magic behind PHP makes it hard to understand what really happens.

Comment: @ErikLandvall Okay, I've added an ASCII graph of a memory approximation.

Comment: +1, thanks for the explanation. But are the memory addresses of $foo and $bar ever different? Also, is the memory addresses of the attribute ever different?

Comment: @ErikLandvall Why are you concerned about memory addresses? PHP is supposed to abstract that away from you, so that you can focus on ... you know, programming :)

Comment: @ErikLandvall But to explain, and it should be obvious from my "diagram", `$bar` and `$foo` are different variables ... unless you declare `function test(&$bar) { }`.

Comment: I just take interest in thees things. It has no baring in the application. I'm just a nerd like that ;)

Comment: Not sure about the reference you mentioned here. See the link I posted in the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41749/discussion-between-jack-and-erik-landvall)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking that in this line

```
$entity->attr = trim($entity->attr);
```

the `$entity` is a new memory or the reference of the old memory. It is the reference of the old memory (or pointer)